# How to get token from request and send the corresponding user to right controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, access-token

I'm building an API in Laravel. The API is accessible from a front end page, using an access key. In my database I've saved the users of this API with their own access key. This key is obtained from Facebook by using the Socialite plugin.

When a user makes a request through an AJAX call (to modify the database), this request should be checked for the access key. The access key should then be found in the users table to find the right user. It actually comes down to two questions:

1. How can the access key be 'intercepted' from the request? Do I do this through middleware?
2. When the right user is found in the table, how do I set this user globally or pass the user to the right controller that is connected to the route?

For example when a user wants to add a new item to the database, the route is like this:

```
Route::post('items', 'ItemController@add')->middleware('tokencheck');
```

I've created a middleware 'tokencheck' that should find the token from the request, but I'm not sure about the usage of middleware in this case. 
After passing this check, the user should be found in the database and passed to the ItemController@add. How do I pass this value?

Thank you!

Comment: Apart of the middleware couldn't you just login the user and the you can get user info from Auth anywhere in your controller?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The back end in Laravel is set up as an API, so it can't remember state. The requests from the client side are all separate. Do you think it would be a good idea to authenticate the user through Auth on every request, or would this take a performance hit?

Comment: I think there would be a performance hit depending on your level of traffic to the api.  Could you skip the middleware and do what the middleware does in the controller action and then you can grab request to get user info and do what you need.